# Organização de arquivos em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas.

```
   classificados
   index.php
   login.php
     -->config
          -->conecta.php
     -->funcoes
          -->banco-usuario.php
     -->headers
          -->cabecalho.php
          -->menu.php
          -->rodape.php
     -->front
          -->painel.php
          -->outrasPaginas.php
```

Se eu incluir no arquivo painel.php o codigo assim`require_once("../headers/cabecalho.php");` vai da erro sempre, pois o arquivo cabecalho.php que esta na pasta headers, chama o arquivo menu, então o arquivo painel.php não encontra o menu, queria fazer isso da forma correta, como eu faço isso?

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: use o caminho absoluto, evite voltar
var/www/html/headers/menu.php 
não é melhor forma de fazer isso, use alguma Fw que cuide desses detalhes para você

Comment: Já pensou em MVC?

Comment: Já guilherme, mas ainda não aprendi, então estou fazendo como dá hehehe

Comment: Usar um framework, adotar arquitetura XYZ... muitas vezes não precisamos disso. Para fins de aprendizado acho super válido o caminho das pedras.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de trabalhar com os caminhos é definir antes dos seus `require` uma constante com o caminho para o diretório raiz do seu projeto. A partir dai você não precisa se preocupar aonde seu script está.

```
<?php

define('ROOT_PATH', '../'); // para os arquivos em um nível em relação a raiz
                            // para subpastas adicione alguns '../' extras

require ROOT_PATH . 'config/conecta.php';
require ROOT_PATH . 'headers/cabecalho.php';
```

Lembre-se que o `require` depende da **localização do arquivo atual**. Se você está no arquivo `cabecalho.php`, sabendo que ambos estão no mesmo diretório, você pode usar o caminho relativo entre os arquivos:

Arquivo `headers/cabecalho.php`

```
<?

define('ROOT_PATH', '../');

require 'menu.php'; // Irá incluir o arquivo headers/menu.php

require ROOT_PATH . 'headers/rodape.php'; // Irá incluir o arquivo headers/rodape.php
                                          // Porém antes ele irá subir um diretório e 
                                          // voltar para headers em seguida
                                          // 'headers/../headers/rodape.php'
```